# Files stay on phone despite deletion

Tags: android, file

i have a problem with saving and deleting files in my Android app.

I download the files via the DownloadManager Request like this:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(),null, item.title + ".mp3");
```

where item.title is a simple String.

The files are stored under android/data/com.me.myapp/files.

I later delete the files using:

```
File myFile = new File(item.guid);
myFile.delete();
```

myFile.delete() returns true.

item.giud is the path i get from the BroadcastReceiver i implemented which receives the Downloadmanager intents

```
cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
```

Everything works fine with accessing the files within the app.

Even when i delete the files and call

```
File myFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null);
File files[] = myFolder.listFiles();
```

the deleted files dont appear in files[] anymore.

But when i open the Folder on my pc which the phone is connected to, i can still see all the files, even the deleted ones and the size of the folder is multiple 100 mbs even tho the files[] array in my app says its empty. However, i cant access(open, copy) any of the files which where "deleted" and thus dont appear in the files[] array in my app anymore. The files i didnt delete in the app work fine tho.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 4.0 your PC has no direct access to the storage, but get information from the MediaScanner, that caches the storage content.
Call this to inform media scanner that content has changed:

```
   File file = new File(absolutePath);
   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
   sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Does this mean, without this broadcast, the device thinks the memory space is still used, or is it just a wrong notification on my windows machine and the memory space can be used on the android device itself.

Comment: I have no idea how it works in those terms. Getting free space from the device's FS is not a big deal, so I suppose that returned value can be OK, but as I said - I'm not sure about it.